# Blocks all files except for the two exceptions. in the Nginx code

Tags: nginx

I use this code for block all files.

```
location / {
  internal;
  alias /home/(direcadmin usser name)/domains/s2.mydomain.com/public_html;
}
```

but I want to allow dl.php and index.php on public_html filder.
how can I do it?

Comment: This location does not process PHP files. To answer your question, we will probably need to see where it fits within your server block.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an alias for something you're to block? Internal blocks external requests, are you providing access to something internal with the alias?

You simply add locations for those URLs. My expression might not be quite right but it should give you the general idea.

```
location ~*  \(dl.php|index.php)$ { 
  // Include PHP code
}
```

Comment: actually I buy a vip script. it has a htaccess, `Order allow,deny
Deny from All

<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
 Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(dl\.php)?$">
 Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
 XSendFile on
</IfModule>` My web server is nginx ,so I should convert it to nginx language. I am not familiar with these codes.by the way I have to enable X-Accel, thats why I use "internal;" via [this guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/)

Comment: I think perhaps you need to hire an administrator. We can help solve problems, but we can't walk you through every step of getting a solution working.

Comment: I've just want to convert these roles. I know how how to put them via direcadmin.

Comment: I used these codes and every thing works fine. `location / {
  internal;
}
location = / { allow all; }`